# Valid Parentheses Java

Tags: java

I am trying to solve the Valid Parentheses problem in Java (described here among other places: [Valid Parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/submissions/))

My code is as follows thus far:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String s) {

        if(s.charAt(0) ="(") {
            if(s.charAt(s.length-1) != ")"){
                system.out.println("false");
            }
        }

        if(s.charAt(0) ="[") {
            if(s.charAt(s.length-1) != "]"){
               system.out.println("false");
            }
        }

        if(s.charAt(0) ="{") {
            if(s.charAt(s.length-1) != "}"){
                system.out.println("false");
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting the following error:

Line 4: error: `unexpected type`

```
   if(s.charAt(0) ="("){
```

Can anyone advise on what the issue is? I can't at the moment figure it out but feel like it's something simple I'm overlooking.

Comment: I think you should start with some simpler problems.  Something where you can learn some Java basics; e.g. string versus character, `=` versus `==`, how to return a value from a method.  Also the basics of Java style; e.g. proper indentation, where to break lines, where to put whitespace in lines, etc.

Comment: Because once you have corrected the basic errors in your syntax, etc, you will find that your current *approach* doesn't give the correct answer.  You need to check that the various brackets are properly balanced and nested; e.g. `"(()"` is bad `"([)]"` is bad ... but your approach would say they are OK.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What programming language did you use before java?

Comment: I'm aware its not a complete solution yet. I was just puzzled why there were so many issues for the initial code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two immediate issues:

1. Character values are single-quoted in Java, e.g. `char c = 'c';`
2. Primitive comparison is done with `==`. The single equals sign `=` is used for assignment.

So that line should be:

```
if(s.charAt(0) == '(') { /* ... */ }
```

Note that this only fixes the most immediate error you're experiencing. After fixing that, there are some more, for example `system.out.println()` should be `System.out.println()`.

And, after fixing that, I think you're still a way off from solving the actual assignment. Just keep at it & good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your answer. [Robby Cornelissen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen) points you out some issues in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57967004/8440358). And I also saw 2 errors in your code.

1. `s.length` should be `s.length()`.
2. You don't have a return statement in the `isValid` method.

**Issue 1**

In the following statement, you are missing the brackets `()` after the length. Length is a method in Java that is used to get the length of a Java String that you know already.

```
if(s.charAt(s.length - 1) != ')')
```

So your above statement should be as follows.

```
if(s.charAt(s.length() - 1) != ')')
```

**Issue 2**

In your `isValid` method it's returning a `boolean` value. The return type of that method is `boolean`. But you are not returning any boolean value inside your method. So you have to add a return statement. It may be,

`return true;` or `return false;` or any `boolean variable` declared inside `isValid` method.

Answer (score 1):

it is best to use stack for valid parentheses in Java

```
class Solution {
public boolean isValid(String s) {
   Stack stack = new Stack();
    for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++){
     if(s[i] =='('){
       stack.push(')')
    }
    else if(s[i] == '['){
     stack.push(']')
    }
    else if(s[i] =='{'){
     stack.push('}')
    }
   else if(s[i] !== stack.pop()){
    return false;
    }    
          
     }
   return true;
  }
}
```